# how to handle null in date field of postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, select, null

I have to ignore rows which have `null` in date column. How can I do it?

```
select s."SR Closed Date"::date,
       s."Service Request Number",
       a."Activity ID" 
from sr_data_master s,
     activity_master a
where s."Service Request Number" = a."Service Request Number"
and a."Service Request Number" is not null 
and a."Service Tag" is not null 
and a."Activity ID" is not null
and s."SR Closed Date"::date is not NULL
group by s."Service Request Number",
         s."SR Closed Date"::date,
         a."Activity ID";
```

I am getting the error:

```
 invalid input syntax for type date: "NULL"
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: why are you using a `group by` if you are not using any aggregates?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I think OP isn't familiar with `DISTINCT` hence the use of `GROUP BY` for every column. Also, look at how join is being done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`null` is a valid value for a date. From the error message, it seems as though you have the string 'null' stored in that column. You could either check for it explicitly:

```
LOWER(s."SR Closed Date") <> 'null'
```

Or just remove the casting to `date` from the `group by` clause.

Answer (score 2):

The error message indicates that your "date" column (which apparently isn't actually a date column) contains the string constant `'NULL'` rather than a real `null` value (because there is no problem casting a real `null` value to `date` value).

You could use the following condition to exclude those rows:

```
and s."SR Closed Date" <> 'NULL'
```

---

But the correct fix for this problem is to store date values in `DATE` columns. Then you don't need the casting and you can't store invalid date values to begin with.